# An elegant way of reading multiple pandas DataFrames and assigning dataframes names in Python using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-wrangling

Excuse my question, I know this is trivial but for some reasons I am not getting it right. Reading `dataframes` one by one is highly inefficient especially if you have a lot of `dataframes` you would like to read from. Remember `DRY - DO NOT REPEAT YOURSELF`

So here is my approach:

```py
files = ["company.csv", "house.csv", "taxfile.csv", "reliablity.csv", "creditloan.csv", "medicalfunds.csv"]

DataFrameName =  ["company_df", "house_df", "taxfile_df", "reliablity_df", "creditloan_df", "medicalfunds_df"]

for file in files:
    for df in DataFrameName:
        df = pd.read_csv(file)
```

This only gives me `df` as one of the `frames`, I am not sure which of them but I guess the last one. How can I `read` through the `csv` files and store them with a dataframe names in the `DataFrameName`

**My goal:**

To have 6 `dataframes` loaded in the workspace spaced in the `DataFrameName`

For example `company_df` holds the data from `"company.csv"`

Answer (score 1):

You could set up

```
    DataFrameDic =  {"company":[], "house":[], "taxfile":[], "reliablity":[], "creditloan":[], "medicalfunds":[]}

    for key in DataFrameDic:
        DataFrameDic[key] = pd.read_csv(key+'.csv')
```

This should return a dictionary containing of dataframes.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```py
files = [
    "company.csv",
    "house.csv",
    "taxfile.csv",
    "reliablity.csv",
    "creditloan.csv",
    "medicalfunds.csv",
]

DataFrameName = [
    "company_df",
    "house_df",
    "taxfile_df",
    "reliablity_df",
    "creditloan_df",
    "medicalfunds_df",
]

dfs = {}

for name, file in zip(DataFrameName, files):
    dfs[name] = pd.read_csv(file)
```

`zip` lets you iterate two lists at the same time, so you can get both the name and the filename.

You'll end up with a dict of DataFrames

Comment: Didn't know that zip feature - really like it!

Comment: Looks great but is it possible to have them as they are in DataFrameName like company_df not referenced like a dictionary

Comment: @PandasJ No, if you want to use the names in `DataFrameName` then you will have to set each variable manually.

Comment: @FrancisWebb it's super handy for these kind of things!

Comment: Okay great! Thanks

Comment: @PandasJ take a look at the answers here for dynamically assigning variable names in python, dictionary seems to be the clearest and easiest way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036700/how-can-you-dynamically-create-variables-via-a-while-loop (Especially given you know your variable names from the get go!)

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary are the way, since you can name their content dynamically.

```
names = ["company", "house", "taxfile", "reliablity", "creditloan", "medicalfunds"]
dataframes = {}
for name in names:
    dataframes[f"{name}_df"] = pd.read_csv(f"{name}.csv")
```

The fact that you have a nice naming convention allows us to append easily the `_df` or `.csv` part to the name when needed.

Answer (score 0):

using pathlib we can create a generator expression then create a dictionary with the file name as the name and the value as the dataframe.

with pathlib we can use the `.glob` module to grab all the csv's in a target path.

replace "\tmp\files" with the path to your files, if your using windows use a raw string or escape the slashes.

```
from pathlib import Path
trg_files = (f for f in Path("\tmp\files").glob("*.csv"))

dataframe_dict = {f"{file.stem}_df": pd.read_csv(file) for file in trg_files}

print(dataframe_dict.keys())

'company_df'

print(datarame_dict['company_df'])
```